# Database architecture of newsletter service (with php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am building a service which provides a newsletter system for the users.

My question is, how to organize it on the database? user opens account -> there is a news row on the data base -> how the email will be stored? I thought about something like:

```
user@mail.com,HASHCODE|user2@anothermail.com,HASHCODE|someone@mail.com,HASHCODE ..
```

(that will be stored on one field of the user's row, HASHCODE for remove the email)

Then using `explode()` to order it in an array. but I don't know if it's the best way to order the mails.. what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store emails in separate table UserEmails and make a relationship with user table. For starting point you may look at [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic609552-361-1.aspx) link
Useremail table will have three fields UseremailID email UserID

```
UseremailID    email         UserID
1           sss@ss.com        1
2           asasf@ssf.com     1
```

I would recommend you to read some relational database so that you get some idea about tables and relationships

Comment: How will be the emails stored on the table UserEmails? Each user has a row on the table UserEmail, then on this row how will be the emails stored?

Comment: I thought about this idea, but is it effective? can be a situation that I have thousand of rows..

Comment: it will be effective as if you follow your approach your database will not be in first normal form which is the least requirement. Almost all of the practical application has large amount of data dbms are efficient enough to handle. If you follow the basics then your code will be maintainable e.g what will u do in future if u want to mark primary email address.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a table structure like this:

```
Table 'subscription'
id int(20) PK auto_increment
email varchar(100) UNIQUE index
```

This will cause you having to insert a new row into the table with a ID and a e-mailaddress (which will both be unique so you dont get double records)

Comment: But how will be the emails stored on the field?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table to store the newsletters and another one to create the relation between users and newsletters so you'll have a better control over your information.

Three tables: User, User_Newsletter, Newsletter

The User_Newsletter will only store the user_id and newsletter_id

Comment: That what I will do, but the important thing its - how will be the emails stored on the table Newsletter? each user has a row, then there is a emails field or something like that? and on this field, how to store the email?

Comment: You will have the email only on the user table, nowhere else, the relation between user and newsletter, user_newsletter, will take care of it...

Answer (score 0):

Database services don't seem to be so flexible (even though they were introduced to be). Normal UNIX filesystem hierarchy and plaintext files are the best way to store information. You don't know the internal structure of a database. But you know everything about your filesystem, including the file permissions and encryption

For example, take [Croud Mail](http://croudmail.com), a free e-mail newsletter service from me. I don't use databases, but it the coding is very flexible and safe.

Comment: Your website is broken.